# Fit to all screen sizes

Tags: java, android

Am I doing it right? I'm trying to make my project that can be used in all different screen sizes, because from the beginning of time I'm creating it using API 17(Nexus One)

```
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/fitnessku"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <compatible-screens>
            <!-- all small size screens -->
            <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
            <!-- all normal size screens -->
            <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
            <!-- all large size screens -->
            <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        </compatible-screens>
```

Comment: I don't see a need to configure this manually. Just add your assets (icons, images, layouts, values for margin, etc) in the directories, like Yodism said. ;) Further information: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create directory for each `layout`. add these directories to your `layout` folder to support multiple screen sizes.

- `layout-small`
- `layout-normal`
- `layout-large`
- `layout-xlarge`
- `layout-xxlarge`

Don't forget to declare it on `manifest` file.